# Using Armatures in Morse Robotic Simulator

Tags: mobile-robot, sensors, robotic-arm, simulator, python

I'm trying to add my own robot in [Morse](https://www.openrobots.org/wiki/morse) 1.1 (using Ubuntu 12.04). I am struggling to add an armature actuator and armature pose sensor to an existing robot. Can someone please explain how this can be done (preferably with some sample code and using the socket interface).

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I hope you have already done [Armature creation](http://www.openrobots.org/morse/doc/1.2/dev/armature_creation.html). If not you need to do that first. Components in MORSE are either robots, sensors or actuators. Robots are mainly containers for sensors and actuators. Assuming you already have an initial simulation environment called mysim, you can create a new sensor with:

```
$ morse add sensor <name> mysim
```

or, for actuators:

```
$ morse add actuator <name> mysim
```

Also I guess you are using Python. You need to implement a sub-class of **morse.core.sensor.Sensor**, respectively of **morse.core.actuator.Actuator**.

```
from morse.core.sensor import Sensor

class MyImageSensor(Sensor):

    _name = "MyImageSensor"
    _short_descr = "A custom Image Sensor"
```

You can know more on [how to add more components](http://www.openrobots.org/morse/doc/1.2/dev/adding_component.html) from here. Also please note that Armature Pose sensor must be added as a child of the armature you want to sense. You can see an example source code [here](http://www.openrobots.org/morse/doc/1.2/_modules/morse/sensors/armature_pose.html) .